# Optimization: Python String Repetition

Tags: python, string, repeat

I have a piece of code that will take a string and repeat it such that the length of the string is x.

```
>>> import math
>>> def repeat(data, length):
        return (data * int(math.ceil(float(length) / len(data))))[:length]
>>> repeat("Hello World", 22)
'Hello WorldHello World'
>>> repeat("Hello World", 20)
'Hello WorldHello Wor'
```

Is there any way to optimize it?
I need this operation to be fast, as it will be used a lot.
Note that this also needs to work with lists.

Comment: Just wondering. Have you actually confirmed that `repeat("Hello World", 22)` is faster than `"Hello World" * 22`

Comment: @WoLpH: He's solving a slightly different problem. He wants "Hello World" (or any string) to be repeated as many times as necessary, but not to exceed N characters in length. Not the same as `string * n`.

Comment: @Brian: indeed, in that case my question is invalid :)
I see no option of optimizing this much further. Simply benchmarking it should be sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be marginally faster:

```
def repeat(string, length):
  L = len(string)
  return string * (length // L) + string[:length % L]
```

I say "might" because a LOT depends on the typical `string` and `length`!  With `'Hello World'` and `61`, I've timed this (on an old Mac laptop) at 1 microsecond vs 1.66 microseconds for yours; with `'Hello World'*100` and `61*123`, 2.08 microseconds vs 2.68 for yours.  Just **how** fast are you requiring, on what length strings, and for what typical values of `length`?

Note `//` is "divide by truncation" (just to ensure this works in Python 3 as well as Python 2;-) even though Stack Overflow is coloring things as if it was a comment mark (as in C++).

Comment: This does speed it up somewhat, It'll have to be good enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to do floating point here; in old Python versions, just say "int(length) / len(string)", and in new versions you can use the "//" operator.  When you get the result, you can just add 1 to make sure it's long enough.  Or, at the cost of a few more additions, you can be more precise and never make the initial string too long:

```
...
    return (data * ((int(length) + len(data) - 1) / len(data)))[:length]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `int(math.ceil(float(length) / len(data)))` you could just use `length/len(data) + 1`. That's not exactly the same but should work as well.

And before trying to make this faster, are you sure that this function is a performance bottleneck? How many thousands of times will you call it each second?

To find out which variant of a function is the fastest one you should profile it, the [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) module is usually useful there.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want optimizate that you need to rewrite your function in C as an extention for python.

You can find information [here](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ext/intro.html).
Sorry for my English, I'm new in this.

Comment: I need to keep it in python, even though "Python" and "speed" don't really go well together.